# File copy operation does not work in a separate thread?

Tags: qt, qthread

I am trying to run code of copying files in other thread so that it may not freeze the GUI of the application.

I found that it does not seem to work in a separate thread.

Why is it not working ?

```
void CopyOperation::run()
{ 
    CopyFilesToFolder(list,sFolder); 
}

bool CopyOperation::CopyFilesToFolder(const QStringList &oFileList,const QString 
&sTargetFolder)
{

if(sTargetFolder.isEmpty())
 {

    status = false;
    return false;
}

QDir dir(sTargetFolder);

if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir(sTargetFolder);

QString sOldDirPath = dir.currentPath();

//if(!dir.setCurrent(sTargetFolder)) return false;

QFile file;
status = true;

foreach(QString sFileName,oFileList)
{
    file.setFileName(sFileName);

    QFileInfo info(sFileName);

    QString newfile =  sTargetFolder + "/" +  info.fileName();

    qDebug() << "\n name = " << newfile;

    if(!QFile::copy(sFileName,newfile))
    //if(!file.copy(newfile))
    {
        qDebug() << "\n File copy failed .. " + file.fileName() + " Error : " + file.errorString();
        status = false;
        break;
    }

}

qDebug() << "\n Result .. " << file.errorString() << "code " <<  file.error();
//dir.setCurrent(sOldDirPath);

return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post code, I just can try to guess what is the problem. Qt has a static function:

```
bool copy ( const QString & fileName, const QString & newName )
```

There is also a copy which is not static:

```
bool    copy ( const QString & newName )
```

Both of them will fail if file defined by `newName` already exists, ie. existing file will not be overwritten. Also, maybe path doesn't exists. Without some portion of code is difficult to guess what is the problem.

Comment: i have added snippet , my CopyOpetaion is QThread derived class.

Comment: I'm not saying that *you* are doing it wrong, but maybe you should read this article: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: It seems that posted code is working (of course, if undeclared 'status' is ignored). I tested it in a simple console application and files are copied. Maybe you didn't start thread properly? What kind of error did you receive? Did you call function 'start()' to start thread execution?

Comment: I am getting unknown error while copying....Yes I have started even thread propertly using start() method.